# Multithreading with a variable number of tasks

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class that needs to compute `n` tasks as quickly as possible (up to 625). Therefore, I want to utilize multithreading so that these computations are run in parallel. After some research, I found the fork/join framework but have not been able to figure out how to implement this.

For example, let there be some class `Foo` (which will be used as an object elsewhere) with some methods and variables:

```
public class Foo {
  int n;
  int[][] fooArray;
  public Foo(int x) {
    n = x;
    fooArray = new int[n][];
  }
  public void fooFunction(int x, int y) {
    //Assume (n > x >= 0).
    fooArray[x] = new int[y];
  }
  //Implement multithreading here.
}
```

I read a basic [tutorial on the Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) that uses `ForkJoinPool` to split a task into 2 parts and use recursion to pass them into the `invokeAll` method. Ideally, I want to do something similar except implement it as a subclass of `Foo` and split the task (in this case, running `fooFunction`) into `n` parts. How should I accomplish this?

Comment: First thing: determine whether multithreading is useful. If your tasks are compute-bound (i.e., limited by the speed of the CPU), then multithreading on a single core will slow it down, not speed it up. The most common way that multithreading is useful is on a task that has enough I/O in it so that, when the machine is waiting on I/O to complete, another thread can be using the CPU (since the CPU is not doing anything while waiting). This gets more complicated with modern CPUs, since some now have multiple cores that some JVMs can use for parallel threads, and then multithreading might help.

Comment: If you determine that multithreading is useful, then consider whether Fork/Join is useful. It is intended for tasks that can be split into different parts recursively, which is only a subset of tasks that can benefit from multithreading. In other words, Fork/Join is a very specific way of doing multithreading, meant for a particular situation. If your task does not split into pieces recursively by nature, then you should use something (anything) else.

Comment: The problem that I am trying to solve involves 5^L convolution operations of matrices that can be around 1000 x 1000 elements (where 5>L>0). There are no I/O  dependent operations and I am assuming that the user will have a multi-core processor. The example I provided is just an extremely simple template which I can adjust to fit my needs later. If there is a better option than fork/join, please post whichever one you think is best as an answer and I'll look into it.

Comment: I am not familiar with the operations on the matrices you describe, including whether they can be solved with recursion. Java's ExecutorService has methods for executing a collection of tasks in parallel, so that's a way that doesn't depend on recursion. You should try to find out how many cores are available at runtime, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of extensive trial-and-error, I finally figured out how to do this myself:

Let there be some class `foo` that needs something that needs many similar (if not identical) tasks to be done in parallel. Let there be some number `n` that represents the number of times that this task should be run, where `n` is more than zero and less than the maximum number of threads that you can create.

```
public class foo {

  //do normal class stuff.

  public void fooFunction(int n) {
    //do normal function things.

    executeThreads(n);
  }

  public void executeThreads(int n) throws InterruptedException {

    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
    List<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        tasks.add(Executors.callable(new Task(i)));

    exec.invokeAll(tasks);
    exec.shutdown();
  }

  public class Task implements Runnable {

    int taskNumber;

    public Task(int i) {

      taskNumber = i;

    }

    public void run() {
      try {
        //this gets run in a thread

        System.out.println("Thread number " + taskNumber);

      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

  }

}
```

This is almost certainly not the most efficient method, and it creates a thread for EVERY task that needs to be done. In other words, this is NOT a thread pool. Make sure that you do not create too many threads and that the tasks are large enough to justify running them in parallel. If there are better alternatives, please post an answer.